# Symfony2 WAMP issue loading CSS and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, css, symfony, wamp

I am working on a project with another developer. I want to use WAMP and he is using LAMP. He is doing the majority of the development so I can not change his code.

The issue I have is with the CSS and Javascript links. For example, the following works in LAMP but not in WAMP:

`<link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`

I can make this work in WAMP by using the following:

`<link href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">`

However I do not want to change this. I want to keep it like this:

`<link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Is there a way of changing something in the config?

Answer (score 0):

The file: **your_project_dir\web\css\bootstrap.min.css** is exist?

If your answer is yes, then:
Open the css file in your browser:
http://your_hostname_or_localhost.com/app_dev.php/css/bootstrap.min.css

And check itt prod mode too:
http://your_hostname_or_localhost.com/css/bootstrap.min.css

What do you get?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was solved by making changes to the httpd.conf.

I implemented the following instructions found here:

https://breinjhel.wordpress.com/2012/10/30/configuring-your-apache-web-server-vhost-for-symfony2-website/

Prior to doing this the url to the project required the full path.